# How to return a PartialView from Core 2 RazorPage ViewModel Handler

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

In Asp.Net MVC, you can easily return a partial view by doing the following:

`return PartialView("ModelName", Model);`

How is this done on a RazorPage ViewModel Handler?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured this out.  It is not nearly as straight forward as it is in MVC.  You have to create an empty `ViewDataDictionary()` and then set its Model property to the partial's populated model.

**View Model / Handler**

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsyncUpdateSearchResults(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string selectedTypes)
{
    int[] types = selectedTypes.Split(",").Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();

    var inventory = await _itemService.GetFiltered(types, null, null, null, null, null, null, startDate, endDate.ToUniversalTime(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (inventory != null)
    {
        SearchResultsGridPartialModel = new SearchResultsGridPartialModel();
        SearchResultsGridPartialModel.TotalCount = inventory.TotalCount;
        SearchResultsGridPartialModel.TotalPages = inventory.TotalPages;
        SearchResultsGridPartialModel.PageNumber = inventory.PageNumber;
        SearchResultsGridPartialModel.Items = inventory.Items;
    }

    var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary()) { { "SearchResultsGridPartialModel", SearchResultsGridPartialModel } };
    myViewData.Model = SearchResultsGridPartialModel;

    PartialViewResult result = new PartialViewResult()
    {
        ViewName = "SearchResultsGridPartial",
        ViewData = myViewData,
    };

    return result;
}
```

I can now call this handler via ajax GET and have it return the partial's HTML.  I can then set the partial's `div` and the partial refreshes as expected.

Here is the AJAX call I'm making:

```
var jsonData = { "startDate": startDate, "endDate": endDate, "selectedTypes": selectedTypesAsString };

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "searchresults/?handler=AsyncUpdateSearchResults",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8"',
    data: jsonData,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#searchResultsGrid").html(result);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: You saved my day! Thank's a lot!

Comment: Great, but i can't get my AJAX GET working, if i return new json it is working fine... any idea or a sample of your Ajax call ? Thank you very much

Comment: Wish I found this 2 days ago.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks alot to TechFisher for figuring it out, here is a bit cleaner example.

```cs
public IActionResult OnGetTestPartial()
{
    return new PartialViewResult()
    {
        ViewName = "Test",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
        {
            Model = new TestPartialData { Data = "inputhere" },
        }
    };
}
```

Partial view in a file name "Test.cshtml" in the same folder as the above class.

```html
@using YourNamespace
@model TestPartialData

<div>Hello, model value: @Model.Data</div>
```

Load it async with jquery

```
$("#someHtmlElementId").load("Your/Path/TestPartial");
```