# Asp.net Core 2 Razor pages: How display ajax partial page return?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, razor-pages

I started my first project with Core 2.0 Razor page, i just have small experience with MVC 5 before (previous projects are working fine).

The problem is simple with Razor pages and AJAX:

- Have a page with list of customers
- Link to edit the customer using AJAX to call the Razor partial page Customer_editPartial (it returns full customer form to a modal DIV in project)

The problem is how to render the partial page returned by the Ajax call? If i return from the customer_editPartial.cs a new json with text it is working, but impossible to display the partial page.

Thank you for your help.

**Here the Page customers.cshtml**

```
<script>
function editCustomer(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Customer_editPartial?id=0",
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            AjaxCustomer_LoadSuccess(response);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert('Customer content load failed.');
        }

    })
}

function AjaxCustomer_LoadSuccess(data) {
    $('#displayContent').html(data);
}
</script>
<a onclick="editCustomer(0);">Edit customer</a>
Here the ajax return<br />
```

**Page Customer_editPartial.cshtml**

```
@page
@model UGM_Web.Pages.AHadmin.Customer_editPartialModel
edit partial form
```

**Here the Customer_editPartial.cs**

```
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
    {
        return Page();
        //return new JsonResult("This is working when i return json text");

    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
    }
```

Comment: Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

The main answer was found with TechFisher in another post ([How to return a PartialView from Core 2 RazorPage ViewModel Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177092/how-to-return-a-partialview-from-core-2-razorpage-viewmodel-handler/49183026#49183026)).

But at same time in my code i got error with ajax datatype (it was set to json instead of html :( Which of course cannot work to receive a partial view...).
Also in the partial page 'Customer_editPartial.cshtml', you need to remove the '@page' directive.

Now in your razor pages to return a partial page you simply need to set a PartialViewresult object and return it:

```
     public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
    {
        Customer_editPartialModel _model = new Customer_editPartialModel(_dbContext);
        var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                                new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary());
        PartialViewResult _resultPartialPage = new PartialViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = "Customer_editPartial",
            ViewData = myViewData,
        };
        return _resultPartialPage;
    }
```

EDIT: A simpler solution

```
return new PartialViewResult() { ViewName = "Customer_editPartial", ViewData = this.ViewData };
```

Comment: If I set [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] before "public IActionResult" it does not work. Without it - works. Maybe you know why?

Comment: Ella, to use Anti Forgery token you need also to add the anti forgery key in your cshtml: @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

Comment: I found my problem: need to add header token name in startup.cs: services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");

Comment: Why not just use the built in controller function PartialView(string viewName, object Model)? It returns a PartialViewResult and binds the data from your model accordingly.